# How to terminate a string that already has a text in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, recv

How can I terminate a string pointer that already has a value?
This is what I tried:

```
char* pointer = "Hello";
pointer = "\0"
```

This doesn't work. I am looking for a way to make something with the same concept of this work, since I am not the one declaring the value of the pointer (a function is).

The function is the `recv` function in `<sys/socket.h>` and it doesn't null terminate it for me.

Comment: Do you know the length of the string?

Comment: How do you intend to determine the end of a string which does not have a terminating `\0`?

Comment: How exactly is the value defined?

Comment: Don't you trust that function which puts text into your string? The function is supposed to null terminate it. If it didn't, at least will it return the length of your string?

Comment: @bereal the function is the recv function in <sys/socket.h> and it doesn't null terminate it for me

Comment: @ArdentCoder Does the recv function in sys/socket return the length of the string received?

Comment: @Cerumersi *"The `recv` function shall return the length of the message written to the buffer pointed to by the buffer argument."* Check this [link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html) for more details.

Comment: So how should I go about terminating it?

Comment: @Cerumersi I don't know much about the `recv` function. but you can check my answer and ask for clarification if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know the `length` of your string in order to null terminate it. In your case, the `recv` function returns the length upon successful execution. It returns `-1` otherwise.

The variable, say `str`, that stores your string should be capable of storing at least `length + 1` characters in it.

Then you can do:

```
ssize_t length = /* Call to recv function */;
if (length != -1)
    str[length] = '\0';
```